# Hibernate relation to jointable

Tags: java, hibernate, table-relationships

I have a problem with Hibernate. I have three tables `jobs`, `actions` and `mails`. For `jobs` and `actions` there is a many-to-many relationship. So I created a join-table `Action_Jobs` which contains the ids of both tables.

Now, how can I build a relationship from the join-table `Action_Jobs` to my third table `mails`? Because from the combination of jobs and actions my mails are identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new table `Action_Jobs` which maps `Jobs` to `Action`. Use the primary key of `Action_Jobs` table and map with `Mails` table. The primary key can be an auto increment column.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks 4 answer but I dont get it. How I map Jobs to Action in another table?

Comment: My assumption is corresponding to each job, there will be an action.Table structure will be like Action_Jobs_Key(autoincrement),jobs_id(Pk of JOBS),action_id(PK of Actions).

Comment: Created an entity Jobs_Action and mapped action and job with @JoinColumn to it. Seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join **Action_Jobs** table with other table because it is not **Entity**. According to your question, **jobs**, **actions** and **mails** are entities.**Action_Jobs** table is used to join actions and jobs table and not entity. So you should join mails table with jobs and actions tables directly.